# Jquery loading image until download starts

Tags: jquery, ajax, pdf, loading-image

I´m trying to have a loading image while waiting for the server to generate a PDF.
When PDF is generated a browser dialog is prompted and that´s when the loading image should hide.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: $(this).attr('href'),
  success: function(response)
  {
   console.log( response );
   $(".report-generator").submit();
  },
 }
});
```

So this code is working.. kind of.. the loading image is shown but only for a short period of time.. the ajax call ends before the file is sent to the user.

This code shows the ajax loader when ever a ajax function is called

```
function initAjaxLoader() {
    $(document.body).ajaxStart(function() { 
        $('#ajax-loader').show();
    }).ajaxStop(function() {
        $('#ajax-loader').hide();
    });
}
```

So how do I keep the ajax call "active" until the download is prompted?

Comment: You can't keep it active since the javascript runs on the client side !

Comment: But can´t I make ajax wait and listen for a respos (file sent) by the server?

Comment: No you can't do that, you could after you "initiate" the generating of the .pdf set a Timeout for 20 seconds and then do the second ajax which loads the .pdf but that's really really crappy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: $(this).attr('href'),
  success: function(response)
  {
   console.log( response );
    $('#result').load('test.pdf', function() {
        $('#ajax-loader').hide();
     });
  },
 }
});
```

Comment: This assumes that the pdf is already generated... and takes about 10-20sec before its generated